# NodeJS: Array and/or JSON filled with \r\n when using promises

Tags: json, node.js, promise

My server is supposed to send me back some data (stored as json) read when asked. To avoid blocking communications, I set-up 2 promises: one to read a file:

```
function readingfile(survey) {
  return new Promise(
    function (data_read, err) {
    fs.stat(`./data/${survey}.json`, function (err, stat) {
      if (err == null) {
        fs.readFile(`./data/${survey}.json`, 'utf8', (err, data) => {
          data_read((data))
        })
      } else
        console.error(`./data/${survey}.json doesnt exist`)
    })
  })
}
```

and one to read all files from a user:

```
function readingusersurveys(user) {
  let questionnaires = [];
  let count = 0;
  return new Promise(
    function (data_read, err) {
      user.surveys.forEach((survey) => {
        readingfile(survey).then(function (all_surveys) {
        count++;
        //console.log((all_surveys)) //ok here
         questionnaires.push((all_surveys))
         if (count == user.surveys.length) {
           console.log((questionnaires)) //not ok here (wtf)
           data_read((questionnaires))
         }
       })
     })
  })
}
```

and the code snippet that send the data:

```
 [...]
 readingusersurveys(req.user).then(function (all_surveys) {
    //console.log(all_surveys)
    questionnaires.push((all_surveys))
    console.log(questionnaires)
    if (questionnaires != null) {
      res.status(200).json({
        questionnaires
      });
    } else {
      res.status(500).json({});
   }
 })
```

but when readingusersurveys() return the data read, it get filled with tons of \r\n making the file unreadable. If I try to place a JSON.parse somewhere, I either: enter a infinite loop or the data become unreadable/undefined (eg: {"asset": ["value"]} become {"asset": [Object]}).

I have tried to place a JSON.parse pretty much everywhere to change comportement but no luck. Any idea how to get rid of \r\n and/or what's missing in my code ? :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many tries, I found out that it wasn't the `JSON.parse` the problem but `questionnaire.push`. It wasn't doing what I though it was doing(adding 2 json array together).

Added the `JSON.parse` here

```
function readingusersurveys(user) {
  let questionnaires = [];
  let count = 0;
  return new Promise(
    function (data_read, err) {
      user.surveys.forEach((survey) => {
        readingfile(survey).then(function (all_surveys) {
        count++;
         questionnaires.push(JSON.parse(all_surveys)) //  <-- HERE
         if (count == user.surveys.length) {
           data_read((questionnaires)) //<-- array of JSON at this point
         }
       })
     })
  })
}

 [...]
 readingusersurveys(req.user).then(function (all_surveys) {
  questionnaires = (all_surveys) //<-- pushing an array of JSON into another array was what created problems
  if (questionnaires != null) {
    res.status(200).json({
      questionnaires
    });
  } else {
    res.status(500).json({});
  }
})
```

If I wanted to do a loop there and add more surveys, I needed to use concat() instead

```
if (questionnaires[0] == null)
   questionnaires = all_surveys
else
   questionnaires = questionnaires.concat(all_surveys)
```